# Android get a string value from specific values folder for one time

Tags: android, string

I want to get some values for one activity in a spesific values folder. But i dont want to update whole language configuration and then get the value.

I want just to get a value from spesific folder.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: use the general value folder which has all  the values, Other values needed only the values needed to be change it will work fine

Comment: I want to show for example "en" strings. But i want to use its "tr" value in background. How is it possible ? @Nithinlal